# Vertical Text Html

Tags: javascript, html, css, vertical-text

How can i make a text with html like in the screenshot below. I just need a simple text but it should be vertically.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQBFe.png)

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use `writing-mode` CSS property.

```css
h1 {
writing-mode: sideways-lr;
}
```

```html
<h1>Safari</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
span{
display:inline-block;
margin-top:20px;
transform:rotate(-90deg);
}
h2{
margin-top:40px;
writing-mode: vertical-lr;
}
```

```html
<span>some text</span>

<h2>more text</h2>
```