How to Display Vertical Text in LightningChartJS
I am working with LightningChartJS and need to display text vertically rather than horizontally. Below is the snippet I've used to display text horizontally, which is based on the documentation.
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { lightningChart , UIElementBuilders, UIOrigins} from "@arction/lcjs";

export default function App() {

  useEffect(() => {

    const lc = lightningChart()
    const chart = lc.ChartXY({container: "chart"});
    // Example, position UI in axis coordinates
    const axisX = chart.getDefaultAxisX()
    const axisY = chart.getDefaultAxisY()
    const textBox = chart.addUIElement(UIElementBuilders.TextBox, { x: axisX, y: axisY })
    .setPosition({ x: 5, y: 5 }).setText("Hello, World!")
    .setOrigin(UIOrigins.LeftBottom)        
  })

  return (
    <div style={{ width: "500px", height: "500px" }} className="chart" id="chart">
    </div>
  );
}


Currently, the text "Hello, World!" is displayed horizontally as shown in this image:

Could someone guide me on how to modify this to display the text vertically?
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Did you read/follow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264527/vertical-text-direction  ?

Hi @Luuk, this is not related to CSS, it is more a lightning chart JS  problem

settextrotation looks promising....

thanks how did you find it? i searched all over the web

I did find it... (good question)   Somehow I did find: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74174385/vertical-text-html , which has a link to SetLabelRotation.  When a Label can be rotated, it should be possible to rotate a Text too, so I searched from there...

BTW: I think I  started here: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+show+text+vertically+lightningchart

as visible in this image

now it is vertical
this is the code:
 const textBox = chart.addUIElement(UIElementBuilders.TextBox, { x: axisX, y: axisY })
    .setPosition({ x: 5, y: 5 }).setText("Hello, World!")
    .setOrigin(UIOrigins.LeftBottom).setTextRotation(90)

by using .setTextRotation(90) as Luke suggested in the comments
